# How do I add an app bar separator

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8

I'm looking to add a separator between app bar commands in my C#/XAML app.
Something similar to what's described at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465309(v=win.10).aspx

How can I do it the right way?

I've seen recommendations to use the Pipe character | or a line. But the recommendations usually look slightly off, compared to what's done in JS/HTML.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Universal Windows 8.1 XAML apps won't allow you to draw a Line in BottomAppBar. Instead you can use **AppBarSeparator** control like this

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar>
        <AppBarButton
            Icon="Delete"
            Label="Delete Icon" />
        <AppBarSeparator />
        <AppBarButton
            Icon="Delete"
            Label="Delete Icon" />
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Comment: This works UWP (Universal Windows Platform) apps (UWA) too.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to do this with a line.  There is an example [here](http://www.pixelvalley.de/?p=952) which looks like this:

```
<Line X1="0" Y1="60"  Margin="0,10,0,0" StrokeThickness="3" Stroke="White"></Line>
```

[image]

Using `Margin`, `X1`, `Y1`, `StrokeThickness` and `Stroke` you should be able to make it look however you want.